# problems with network-online-target dependency in systemd

Tags: startup, systemd

I am trying to:

- run a bash script on booting Kubuntu (Ubuntu 19.10)
- after my internet connection is established
- using systemd (using the network-online.target service)

I wrote the .service file below. It refers to an sh executable that tests if IPv4 is up via ping.

- The script (which is executable by all) works, it tells me I'm up when I run it manually.
- Systemd calls the script successfully on boot, I can see the script has run after booting

However, somehow systemd calls my service before my internet connection is up while it should wait for the internet connection before running. Anybody any idea what is going wrong here? See code below:

**My script (/home/me/scripts/testInternetConnection.sh):**

```
if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
  echo "IPv4 is up"  >> /home/me/Desktop/result.txt
else
  echo "IPv4 is down" >> /home/me/Desktop/result.txt
fi
```

**My service file definition (/etc/systemd/system/myConnectionTester.service):**

```
[Unit]
Description=test internet connection
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=me
WorkingDirectory=/home/me
ExecStart=/home/me/scripts/testInternetConnection.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=network-online.service
```

Thanks in advance!

N.

Comment: Remove the `WantedBy=network-online...`, and add a `#!/bin/sh` to the start of `testInternetConnection.sh` (and ensure it is `chmod +x`). Add `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i eth0` where eth0 is the interface you are using. This waits until the interface is up, in case network-online is too early.

Comment: Thanks so far! Could you be so kind as to elaborate on what you mean by "Add /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i eth0".? As in, do I add that line to one of my files (and if so where), Note that in my /usr/lib/systemd directory, there is no file named systemd-networkd-wait-online..

Comment: I think `systemd-networkd-wait-online` appeared in version 219. There's an ubuntu [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man8/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.8.html) which says it should be under `/lib/systemd/` (I was looking at my Fedora system which differs). You could add it to the start of your `testInternetConnection.sh` script before the ping.

Comment: Hi meuh, that command returns an error. one for each interface: Failed to update link state, ignoring: No data available

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesn't help. I've not tried it before. It seems your only hope is to repeat your `ping` command in a loop a few times in order to get a reply when the link is up, or to give up if the link is really down.